# Intellij maven structure

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am new on Intellij and have some troubles about **checking out an existing maven** project. In the past using eclipse when I check out an **existing maven project** it checks out the a pom file and the "src" folder to project explorer view, then I used to right click project, configure, configure as maven project. This used to create a file structure on the project explorer view like this

```
src/main/java ; src/main/resources ; src/main/test
```

Now When try to do the same thing with IntelliJ, after I check out the project I couldnt find a way like eclipse to "configure as maven project", the src folder structure is hierarchical and  you click through deep to get where you want instead of tidy looking folder names like "src/main/java" etc .

IS this how Intellij works or I am missing something

Comment: Did you ever get it to show like "src/main/java" (like eclipse) instead of hierachically?

Comment: @acdcjunior no, it is still hierachical. but I have no problem with it

Comment: Oh, well, I guess this is the "IntelliJ way", I guess I'll have to get used to it. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 4):

Either you can File > New Project > Maven Module (Intellij will ask if its using existing sources)

Or use File > Import Project > browse through the folder structure : Intellij auto detects the POM file as a valid project format

I think even if you right click on the project inside Intellij and add framework support > maven it will also import accordingly (not sure of this one )

Comment: tnx, I have 1 parent module and 2 child modules, should I import only parent project?

Comment: @Spring only the parent.

Answer (score 0):

In your folder, navigate to the pom.xml and Open With >> IntelliJ